# Как удалить один конкретный символ в конце строки

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список

```
lst = ["NAME___", "SURNAME_", "TEST_ACC", "ID__"]
```

Как можно удалить один конкретный символ с конца (_).
Должно получиться так

```
lst = ["NAME__", "SURNAME", "TEST_ACC", "ID_"]
```

Думал что можно так, но так удаляет все символы

```
lst = [t.rstrip("_") for t in lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался сделал пока так

```
lst = ["NAME___", "SURNAME_", "TEST_ACC", "ID__"]
lst = [t[:-1] if t[-1] == "_" else t for t in lst]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Да, короче, кажется, не получится сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix)

Comment: @nomnoms12 А, ну да, если питон 3.9, то есть такое дело

Answer (score 1):

```py
lst = ["NAME___", "SURNAME_", "TEST_ACC", "ID__"]
lst2 = []
for x in lst: lst2.append(x[:-1] if x[-1:] == "_" else x)
print(lst2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 3.9 Вы можете воспользоваться методом [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix).

***Пример:***

```py
lst = ['NAME___', 'SURNAME_', 'TEST_ACC', 'ID__']
lst = [s.removesuffix('_') for s in lst]
print(lst)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['NAME__', 'SURNAME', 'TEST_ACC', 'ID_']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
lst = ["NAME___", "SURNAME_", "TEST_ACC", "ID__"]
def cut_last(item: str):
    return re.sub(r'_$', '', item)

print(
    list(
        map(
            cut_last,
            lst
        )
    )
)
```

Output

```py
# ['NAME__', 'SURNAME', 'TEST_ACC', 'ID_']
```